# How to accept a file and then store it in cloud storage

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-storage

I am using expressjs (all newest versions of express, node, and npm). I have create a route such as this:

```
router.post("/", function(req, res, next) {
});
```

This route will need to be able to have a file (image/video/docx,etc) uploaded and needs to then be stored on a cloud storage service (Google Storage). I do not want to store anything on the server that express is running on, just want to receive the file and pass it on over to Google Cloud Storage. I see there are some libraries which do this in addition to express, but I couldn't not find how to do it using just express.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/nodejs

Comment: I am not using drive. I am using Google Cloud Storage.

Answer (score 0):

I think your clients might be able to upload directly to GCS by constructing a HTML form. Basically you can create a signed url and embed it in the form and then on submit, the upload goes straight to GCS and your app doesn't need to handle it at all.

See: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object